# Swift Error - Cannot load underlying module for 'MessageKit'

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to create a Chat Apps using MessageKit, but when creating the ViewController and import the MessageKit, I get an error as below

> Cannot load underlying module for 'MessageKit'

this is my PodFile

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'GanChat' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'MessageKit'

end
```

and this is my ViewController

```
import UIKit
import MessageKit

class ChatViewController: MessagesViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    senderId = "1234"
    senderDisplayName = "Heri"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Did you run pod install?

Comment: yes, I've been run pod install

Comment: Dumb question, sorry: after running `pod install` did you open the `xcworkspace` file or the `xcodeproj` file? You should open the workspace.

Comment: Common fixes to rule out first - 1) make sure you open the workspace file (as huwr suggests). 2) Do a clean (Cmd + Shift + K) and then build (Command + B) for Generic iOS device.

Comment: @huwr I open the xcworkspace file after running pod install.

Comment: @LouisLeung thanks, its working now

Comment: Sure thing @rafitio - what was the specific fix, so people searching this post will know the answer also?

Comment: @LouisLeung, I following your way to  do clean (Cmd + Shift + K) then its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the OP, the fix for the issue was to clean the project with (Cmd + Shift + K) before building the project.